# Creating a push segue from clicked link in a webView popover

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, segue, uipopovercontroller

I have a view controller (MainViewController) that displays another view controller with a webView (WebViewController) through a storyboard popover. This WebViewController displays html that is read in using "webView.loadHTMLString." The html that is presented in this popover contains hyperlinks that the user can click.

I am looking for a way to, on link click in the popover view, "push" segue to the WebViewController So that the MainViewController transitions to the WebViewController and displays the link that was clicked in full size.

Both the MainViewController and the WebViewController are on the same navigation stack.

I am working in swift but if there are solutions in objective c that would work as well! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UIWebViewDelegate Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:), the following function should be implemented and called if you make your class conform to UIWebViewDelegate:
`webView(_:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)`

You can check to see if the navigationType is a link by checking if it is .LinkClicked.
From there you can handle whatever needs to be done to open the link, such as pushing to another view controller and passing the NSURLRequest as a parameter.